# resolve scope in a <script> on a partial in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have defined my router as:

```
.when('/profile/:id/:wgId/:fileId', {
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            controller: 'templateController'


        })
```

Controller as:

```
myApp.controller('templateController',function($scope,socket){

    $scope.street_name = "testName";


});
```

On template.html:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var test = {{street_name}};
</script>
```

However, it is not resolved. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You can't (in a simple way) have access to the scope outside AngularJS. The real question is why do you want to do that?

Comment: The reason is that my partial has already been working with jquery and javascripts and angular for the rest of the application. Moving template to angular completely would be a hassle, and hence finding a solution to it.